# concatenate two strings in arduino then do the opposite

Tags: arduino, concatenation, string-concatenation

I need to concatenate two strings in arduino then I will need to do the opposite.
For exemple make `stringOne` and `stringTwo` concatenated then with another instruction separate the `stringOne` from `stringTwo`

Comment: you can use standard C functions for the string handling to split or concatenate strings (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling).

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use standard C functions as pointed out, if your first string is long enough to contain both strings then you can use this:

`strcat(firstString, secondString);`

otherwise you will have to do this:

```
char *output = (char *)malloc(strlen(firstString) + strlen(secondString) + 1);
strncpy(output, firstString, strlen(firstString));
strcpy(output + strlen(firstString), secondString + 1);
```

you may want to zero your memory and make sure the string is still null terminated.

to split the strings you can use strncpy as well.

```
char stringOne[50]; //use whatever seems good
char stringTwo[50]; //use whatever seems good
memset(stringOne, '/0', sizeof(stringOne));
memset(stringTwo, '/0', sizeof(stringTwo));
strncpy(stringOne, combinedString, length of first string);
strncpy(stringTwo, combinedString + length of first string, length of second string);
```